# Chess : how to count all legal moves on diagonals for a queen placed in $(x,y)$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I'm trying to get a formula that counts all legal spaces over diagonals for a given point $(x,y)$, e.g.:

[image]

In the above image, you can see there are $13$ legal squares over diagonals.

Is there a formula to count that?

---

I tried to make my own equation to get that without make any loop, but It doesn't work.
What I achieved, for example point $(5,1)$ with board length $5$:

1. `Row - 1` $\rightarrow 5 - 1 = 4$.
2. Then, If `row > column`, then `Length - row`, else `length - column`.

It would be: $(5 - 1) + (5 - 5) + (5 - 5) + (5 - 5) = 4$. And that's correct.

This formula work for most of points, but there are some special cases, e.g., in the middle of the board.

Thus, I was wondering if there is an equation for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an $N\times N$ board, the diagonal with positive slope contains $N- |x-y|$ squares, and the diagonal with negative slope contains $N - |(N+1-x)-y| = N - |x+y-N-1|$ squares. But both of these count the square $(x,y)$ twice; if we don't want to count it, we should subtract $2$. (Thanks to John Omielan for pointing this out in the comments!) In total, the formula is
$$
   2N-2 - |x-y| - |x+y-N-1|.
$$

Comment: Thank you!, I may missed to figure it out, but I get wired output (not correct), In some cases it work and In other it won't.

Comment: e.g: `((2 * n) + (x - y) - (x + y - n - 1))` for n = 8 ,x = 4, y = 3, It should be 11 and I get 19

Comment: @IbrahimAli Actually, using your example, the formula provided in the answer gives $13$, not $19$. However, note it's only correct if you wish to count the square at $(4,3)$ twice. Otherwise, I believe the correct formula should subtract $1$ at the end to avoid this double-counting, or if you wish to exclude this square completely, it should subtract $2$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @IbrahimAli Don't forget the absolute values!

Comment: @MishaLavrov You are welcome. Based on the example given in the question, plus what the OP expected in the comment above, it seems the expectation is not include the square $(x,y)$. Thus, subtracting $2$ from your formula appears to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @IbrahimAli As mentioned in my comment, and is now mentioned in the answer as well, the provided formula counts the square $(x,y)$ twice. However, it seems you want to exclude that square, so you need to subtract $2$, so you'll get in your example $13 - 2 = 11$, as expected.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I really confused here, but, some inputs are correct with addin **-2**, and some other are not the input's that doesn't work with **-2**, It work without it..

Comment: @IbrahimAli Please give a specific example that you believe doesn't work correctly with the provided formula after you subtract $2$ from the result. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan $((2 * n) - 2 - (x - y) - (x + y - (n - 1))) - 2$ For n  = 8, x =4, y=3, output 11 as expected, For n = 5 same x,y, output = 2, expected 6 editing formula to $(2 * n) - 2 - (x - y) - (x + y - n - 1))$ output = 6 as expected,

Comment: @IbrahimAli The formula should always be $2n-2 - |x-y| - |x+y-n-1|$, not $|x+y-(n-1)|$. For $n=8, x=4, y=3$, we get $2\cdot8-2 - |4-3|-|4+3-8-1| = 14 - |1| - |{-2}| = 11$. For $n=5, x=4, y=3$, we get $2\cdot 5 - 2 - |4-3| - |4+3-5-1| = 8 - |1| - |1| = 6$. Both work.

Comment: @IbrahimAli As Misha stated, don't forget absolute values. The vertical bars, e.g., $|x+y-N-1|$, means use the value if it's $\ge 0$, else the negative of it, so you always get a value $\ge 0$. In your case, the result is $2 \times 5 - 2 - |4 - 3| - |4 + 3 - 5 - 1| = 10 - 2 - 1 - 1 = 6$, as you say is expected. Note the provided formula now includes subtracting $2$, as in the first part of $2N - 2 \ldots$, so you don't need to do it again. Thus, for your $1$st example, you get $2 \times 8 - 2 - |4 - 3| - |4 + 3 - 8 - 1| = 16 - 2 - |1| - |-2| = 16 - 2 - 1 - 2 = 11$, i.e., correct with no $-2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, I didn't pay attention to the absolute values..

Comment: @MishaLavrov Please, If you can help... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143691/how-to-get-legal-diagonals-for-x-y-in-only-one-directions