# How to get legal diagonal count for (x,y) In only one direction?

Tags: geometry

In my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143269/how-to-get-all-legal-diagonals-for-x-y-point) I get all legal diagonals for $(x,y)$ point on coordinate plane, Now I'm trying to get the diagonal for only one direction. e.g:
$(3,4)$ on board length 5, the top right would be 1, top left 2, bottom right  1 and top left 2, I tried to figure out the equation for that, but I missed it up.

Reference much appreciated, Thank you.